# Как сохранить статистику docker stats (NetIO)?

Tags: docker, сеть

Интересует возможность сохранения статистики **NET I/O**.

Если я остановлю контейнер и запущу снова, то статистика будет сброшена, интересует возможность сохранения статистики, чтобы в дальнейшем понимать сколько было использовано трафика в каждом контейнере за определенный период времени, пробовал инструмент **cAdvisor**, но там не нашел такой возможности.

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME                                     CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O          BLOCK I/O         PIDS
d18a8f763cf0   zabbix-docker_zabbix-web-nginx-pgsql_1   0.09%     51.95MiB / 512MiB     10.15%    53.3kB / 241kB   35MB / 20.5kB     13
126c09fe9f94   zabbix-docker_zabbix-server_1            0.35%     39.32MiB / 971.6MiB   4.05%     5.61MB / 305kB   14.8MB / 2.78MB   55
ff861254bcff   zabbix-docker_postgres-server_1          0.21%     108.2MiB / 971.6MiB   11.13%    311kB / 5.64MB   50.6MB / 573kB    36
```

Comment: docker volumes посмотрите)

Comment: Я посмотрел, там ничего нет относительно статистики

Answer (score 0):

https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/docker поставь и сохраняй всё с графиками и историей